# How to cast between compatible method pointers?

Tags: delphi, polymorphism, function-pointers, delphi-xe7

I have two different method pointers.

```
type
  TComponentMethod = procedure(const AComponent: TComponent) of object;
  TFormMethod = procedure(const AForm: TForm) of object;
```

The only difference is the type of the argument, but both are object references so it should not make any difference from the calling convention point of view.

(However it could be a type safety problem, because of co- / contravariance.)

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure M2(const AForm: TForm);
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  FormMethod: TFormMethod;
  ComponentMethod: TComponentMethod;
begin
  FormMethod := M2;
  // How to cast this?
  ComponentMethod := M2;
end;
```

The compiler doesn't let me do it.

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(32): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TComponent' and 'TForm'
```

Is there any way to type cast a method pointer to another "compatible" method pointer?

Comment: They are absolutely ***not compatible*** (not even with quotes). If you've implemented `M2` without using `TForm` members (as this would break if you call `ComponentMethod` with a non-form), then there's no point declaring `M2` to take a `TForm` input.

Comment: This is only the simplified example of a much more complex problem. I know that I have to make sure that the methods are only called with the correct type (or some subtype). The method pointer cast is contravariant.

Comment: This and your other comment make your question look even more like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You haven't told us about your real problem because you've come up with an idea to solve it using type-specific callback events; but stored generically. This idea leads to dodgy typecasting, possibly boiler-plate edits whenever you want to extend the types supported, and is quite restrictive in that it only works for single parameter callbacks. I'm still not clear on what you're trying to achieve; but wonder if you've considered Command objects?

Comment: The original problem was to replace a very long "if .. else if" ladder by a dictionary to avoid writing boiler plate code, simplified example: http://fpaste.org/355000/56062146/

Comment: From that code I would make a generic `TComponentMethod<T: TComponent> = procedure(const AComponent: T) of object;` method and use that as argument for your RegisterMethod method. Internally you can hardcast that to the non generic `TComponentMethod` type and put that into the dictionary.

Comment: That is what I'm doing now, except for the generic type constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var
  FormMethod: TFormMethod;
  ComponentMethod: TComponentMethod;
begin
  FormMethod := M2;
  ComponentMethod := TComponentMethod(FormMethod);
end;
```

As far as I can see, the trick is that you need to assign to a temporary local variable before subsequently assigning that to `ComponentMethod`.

As you know, this is not typesafe. If `ComponentMethod` is invoked with an argument that is not derived from `TForm`, then the compiler won't be able to save you.

Answer (score 3):

They're not compatible.

If `M2` takes a `TForm` as one of its inputs, the compiler can reasonably expect form methods/members to be accessed in the body of `M2`.

A `TComponentMethod` event handler only requires a `TComponent` instance to call it. So the combination (if the compiler allowed it) would make it possible to access `TForm` members on `TComponent` instances. (***Obviously a recipe for disaster***.)

E.g.

```
procedure TForm1.M2(const AForm: TForm);
begin
  AForm.ModalResult := mrCancel;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ComponentMethod: TComponentMethod;
begin
  ComponentMethod := M2;

  //The next line is legal. But if the previous line were legal,
  //you'd attempt to access TForm(AComponent).ModalResult ...
  //An AV if you're lucky, and weird behaviour if you're not.
  ComponentMethod(TComponent.Create(Self));
end;
```

---

That said, you can perform a hard-typecast. However, `TComponentMethod(M2)` wouldn't work because the compiler wants to call `M2` almost any time you use the identifier. It's only a bit of "compiler magic" that that allows `FormMethod := M2` in the first place. So you'd need an intermediate event handler variable to hold a reference to `M2`. And because an event handler variable is not a function, it can be typecast without trying to call it.

```
Temp := M2;
ComponentMethod := TComponentMethod(Temp);
```

***WARNING*** This is a terrible idea, but it works:

- Reminder: The `ComponentMethod` variable can be used as follows: `ComponentMethod(AComponentThatsNotAForm)`.
- If you can **truly guarantee** that the previous call is safe because of how `M2` is implemented, then you should have declared M2 as follows: `procedure M2(const AComponent: TComponent);` (If it doesn't need a form instance to do its job, don't ask for a form instance.) ... *And you wouldn't have to bother trying so desperately to find a way to shoot yourself in the foot.*

Comment: I have a use case where it makes sense. I don't only store the TComponentMethod pointer, but also the original TClass and test using "is" and ".InheritsFrom". The whole purpose is to store different methods in a container which would normally not work.

Answer (score 0):

Davids answer is fine. I have written a generic method to avoid having to declare a temporary variable of the source type each time i cast.

```
type
  TOneArgMethod<T> = procedure(const A: T) of object;


function TForm1.CastMethod<TFrom, TTo>(AFrom: TOneArgMethod<TFrom>)
  : TOneArgMethod<TTo>;
var
  Method: TMethod;
begin
  Method := TMethod(AFrom);
  Result := TOneArgMethod<TTo>(Method);
end;
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do something that's such a terrible idea so often that you need a helper method to make it easy to do? I strongly suspect you'd get much better mileage re-examining your design rather than making your code extremely fragile by performing unsafe type-casts.